# datetime.date - Can't create correct input in script

Tags: python-3.x

When I use datetime.date like beyond it works:

```
endeDate = datetime.date(1999, 6, 7)
```

when I create the input in my script it looks same as I would type in manually :

```
yerMonthDay = (str(year) + str(", ") + str(month) + str(", ") + str(day))
print(yerMonthDay)
1999, 6, 7
```

I know that datetime.date can just work with integer. I am not able to create the correct input for datetime.date in my script. I tried different things but nothing works:

```
endeDate = datetime.date(int(year) + int(month) + int(day))
TypeError: function missing required argument 'month' (pos 2
    
endeDate = datetime.date(f'{int(year)}{str(", ")}{int(month)}{str(", ")}{int(day)}')
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str
    
endeDate = datetime.date(int(year) + str(", ") + int(month) + str(", ") + int(day))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

endeDate = datetime.date(int(year) + int(", ") + int(month) + int(", ") + int(day))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ', '
```

It would be great if you could tell me how I can create the input in my script that datetime.date(xxx) accepts it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `year`, `month`, and `day` are integers, just use

```
year_month_day = datetime.date(year, month, day)
```

There's no need to try and format a string with commas `,` in it. [`datetime.date()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date) takes 3 arguments, and you need to supply them the normal way.

Comment: Thanks it works. I tried this variation before as well but it was not integer.  In datetime.date () it is not possible to convert it to int. Now I converted it before to int and it works.